# How to parallelize a CPU-intesive data processing task using Python?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing, batch-processing, distributed-computing

I'm creating some code to perform OCR on a large dataset of pdfs and write the extracted text into a csv. This is done using a combination of libraries such as Imagemagick, Pillow, PyOCR (Tesseract) etc and has been tested on a small sample of data.

The data contains a large number of folders (~2500) each with around 15 pdfs. One csv is created for the pdfs in each folder and processing each folder takes around 10 mins. This would mean running the OCR on all the 2500 folders would take around 18 days, which is simply too long. I need to be able to run the whole process in 7 days or less.

So, I'm looking into parallelizing the processing of each subfolder as the processing of each is independent of any other subfolder. My first approach was to use the `concurrent.futures` module to create a ProcessPool like so:

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(4)
futures = ([executor.submit(run_pdf_to_text_ocr, folder) for folder in sub_folders])
concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
```

Here `run_pdf_to_text_ocr()` is the main function that runs the processing for each folder. There are some issues with the same resources being used by the processes and I'm resolving those so that each folder (process/thread) is isolated in its resource usage.

Naturally, this processing pipeline is very CPU-intensive and maxes out the processor while it is running. I'm going to spin up a large AWS EC2 instance to eventually do the full run. So, what I want to know before I embark with that is:

> If this approach I'm taking is the correct one? 
>   Are there any alternate approaches I can take to do this in a better way? Is using distributed processing something I should do instead? What can I do to properly monitor this long-running pipeline so I can be aware of any problems that might arise in the middle of processing?

I'm mostly comfortable with Python and would prefer a solution using it, as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think `multiprocessing` module is what you want.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

workers = Pool()
workers.apply_async(your_task_function, args=(args_for_this_task))
workers.join()
```

So you can easily split your whole task into small ones and then pass to multi cpus. The tasks you apply will be placed in the `workers`'s queue.

Additionally, to monitor the error, you can pass an error callback like this: `workers.apply_async(your_task_function, args=(args_for_this_task), error_callback=error_callback)`

Further, you can use `multiprocessing.Manager` to easily share the variables across the processes which could even on different machines.

Answer (score 1):

### Prologue

This job can be done in one day or just overnight, but this is NOT a job for any parallel-processing architecture. Why?

- There is zero-need to maintain parallelism among a cohort of { thread- | process-}-executions.
- There is zero-dependency / intercomms / synchronisation among any pair/group in the herd
- There is zero-need to share a content / context of the individual, independent OCR-jobs
- So why to pay all those immense performance-costs and yet-more, the Python GIL-lock penalty ( many threads, but just GIL-locked to **just 1-executes** + **all others wait** in queue to receive the GIL-lock permission to run a few steps forward and again, step-back and release the GIL-lock in a pure-SEQ-relay-race ( ?!?! ) )

So, in other words, the proper architecture ought seek for a feasible performance scaling ( the more linear the better ), not for harnessing a true-parallel section in an otherwise just sequential imperative-code. It **could be also artificially expensive on AWS scaling to rent a dinosaurus-sized emulated code-execution instance**, just for the sake of many just-concurrent thread-execution ( still having a risk of all that devastated into GIL-stepped SEQ-relay 1-works + ALL-wait ), whereas other scenarios can work adaptively and cost-efficiently.

The last principal objection is, that smart system architectures follow rather the logic of workflow execution and optimise performance-constraining sections first, rather than trying to convince the design-board with a few SLOCs that just look cool in schoolbook examples, but never else.

---

[image]

### [Smarter way goes into Adaptive, Distributed-processing Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D)

Why?

- One can add performance on-the-fly ( adding more lightweight Worker-units, if Time requires, Budget permits until all CPU-capacities are steadily on 100% )
- One can receive incremental deliveries ( finished workunits ( OCR'd PDFs )  ) from the Distributed-processing as they appear finished, not after waiting, outside of any processing-control, 7 days to get first or getting nothing at all, if something went wrong under the hood.
- One can even prototype / deploy / adapt / modify / update / redesign the way the processing takes place, while still keeping the work being done -- live-updates can take place smoothly and without loosing any time and already performed work-units, processed so far by the previous Worker-version(s).

All that summed up, forget to use Python built-ins ( even if adding efforts to modify them into a GIL-released forma and shape ) but rather fully evaluate the performance, scaling and ROI-benefits of massively scalable Distributed-processing solution.

- Adding Worker-nodes when needed and how many needed ( even hundreds or thousands into an overnight shift orchestrated in an office-type environment or as granted by available IaaS vouchers or other (almost)-zero-cost processing nodes )
- Having additional signalling tools as needed ( can ask Worker(s) just from terminal to report their actual state / ETA / remote CPU-load / ... )
- Runs over **`tcp://`** for indeed heterogeneous distributed system ( AWS and other external IaaS provisioning vehicles ) and many other `{ inproc:// | ipc:// | pgm:// | epgm:// }` transport-classes for indeed all powerful design approaches to high-performance designs.

[image]

**Epilogue:** needless to warn you PIL is extremely slow, so if in a need to accelerate the individual document-job-processing, profiler will most probably point on this one hot-spot.